# performing Groupby in large data set MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have data like this in my table in success column 1 -> success 0 -> failed

```
MariaDB [mark_db]> select * from Ntv_statistics;
```

Gives :

```
| DateTime            | Address      | Msisdn       | ReqType| Success      |
|---------------------|--------------|--------------|--------|--------------|
| 2020-12-21 18:20:32 | ha@google.com| 919876543211 | Reg    |      1       |
| 2020-12-21 18:21:34 | hb@yahoo.com | 919876543211 | DReg   |      1       |
| 2020-12-21 18:22:16 | hb@yahoo.com | 919876543213 | Reg    |      0       |
| 2020-12-21 18:24:27 | hb@yahoo.com | 919876543214 | Reg    |      1       |
| 2020-12-21 18:26:34 | ha@google.com| 919876543211 | Reg    |      0       |
```

After filtering I want data something like this:

| Msisdn | ReqType | Success(Count) | failure(count) | total(count) | Success(%) | Failure(%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 919876543211 | Reg | 1 | 1 | 2 | 50 | 50 |
| 919876543211 | DReg | 1 | 0 | 1 | 100 | 0 |
| 919876543213 | Reg | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 100 |
| 919876543214 | Reg | 1 | 0 | 1 | 100 | 0 |

How to get this data from the first table

I tried query like below but that's not proper

```
select Msisdn,ReqType,count(Success) as success,count(Success) as failure,count(*) as total 
from Ntv_statistics 
group by Msisdn,ReqType;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation with boolean expressions we can try:

```sql
SELECT
    Msisdn,
    ReqType,
    SUM(Success = 1) AS Success_Count,
    SUM(Success = 0) AS Failure_Count,
    100.0 * SUM(Success = 1) / COUNT(*) AS Success_Pct,
    100.0 * SUM(Success = 0) / COUNT(*) AS Failure_Pct
FROM Ntv_statistics
GROUP BY
    Msisdn,
    ReqType;
```

Comment: Hi Sir, It worked, Thanks for the answer it helped me to gain knowledge on writing query